# using unsafe code in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, unsafe, system.diagnostics

trying to debug a modified code to be using `unsafe` generates an error 
i dont know if my code is correct with the astrics (so please check if i put those correctly) though there is another issue apart from that... with compiler options in **asp.net** 
as opposed to Windows apps, there's no sutible place to check/uncheck the option to using unsafe

and as far as i could get to info about that envolves dealing with the Web.Config "manually"

so i was doing that , added a code to `Web.Config`, 
there are two versions of users suggesting to put code within configuration section or within the same scope of `debug=true` ...

so i put it in both(not at same time , but tried both (:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
 <system.codedom>
   <compilers>
     <compiler language="C#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>....my secret connection here...
   then rest of configs..
     .....




    struct IO_COUNTERS
    {
        public ulong ReadOperationCount;
        public ulong WriteOperationCount;
        public ulong OtherOperationCount;
        public ulong ReadTransferCount;
        public ulong WriteTransferCount;
        public ulong OtherTransferCount;
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    unsafe static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr* ProcessHandle, out IO_COUNTERS* IoCounters);


    private struct PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS
    {
        public uint cb;
        public uint PageFaultCount;
        public uint PeakWorkingSetSize;
        public uint WorkingSetSize;
        public uint QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint PagefileUsage;
        public uint PeakPagefileUsage;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 40)]
    [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    unsafe static extern bool GetProcessMemoryInfo(IntPtr* hProcess, out PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS* Memcounters, int size);
```

this is the calss that implements native pinvok codes

(at the beginning i was trying to test native vs managed / .net approach )
but before even trying the pinvoke vs .net i dived strait to check on 
performance btween pinvoke ***unsafe** vs .net

so this part is still in "safe mode" 
should it be also treated with the astrics  ?

```
static class Nat
    {
        public static class IO
        {
            public static Dictionary<string, ulong> GetALLIO(Process procToRtrivIO)
            {
                IO_COUNTERS counters;
                Dictionary<string, ulong> retCountIoDict = new Dictionary<string, ulong>();
                GetProcessIoCounters(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out counters);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadOperationCount", counters.ReadOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteOperationCount", counters.WriteOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherOperationCount", counters.OtherOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadTransferCount", counters.ReadTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteTransferCount", counters.WriteTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherTransferCount", counters.OtherTransferCount);
                return retCountIoDict;
                //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
                //    " Mb of data.";

            }
        }
        public static class Mem
        {
            public static Dictionary<string, uint> GetAllMem(Process procToRtrivMem)
            {

                PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS MemCounters;
                Dictionary<string, uint> retCountMemDict = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
                GetProcessMemoryInfo(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out MemCounters, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS))); //MemCounters.cb);
                retCountMemDict.Add("cb", MemCounters.cb);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PageFaultCount", MemCounters.PageFaultCount);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PeakWorkingSetSize", MemCounters.PeakWorkingSetSize);
                retCountMemDict.Add("WorkingSetSize", MemCounters.WorkingSetSize);
                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaPagedPoolUsage);

                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PagefileUsage", MemCounters.PagefileUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PeakPagefileUsage", MemCounters.PeakPagefileUsage);

                return retCountMemDict;
                //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
                //    " Mb of data.";

            }
        }

    }
```

sorry for that, but the update is i missed the part of :
compiler option

```
compilerOptions="/unsafe" // <<-- you can add this to the compiler config line.
```

though still . my problems only started then cause there is not only one error :

```
Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe
```

but errors all over the place !

first one for instance :

```
            public static Dictionary<string, ulong> GetALLIO(Process procToRtrivIO)
            {
                IO_COUNTERS counters;
                Dictionary<string, ulong> retCountIoDict = new Dictionary<string, ulong>();

            --->>   GetProcessIoCounters(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out counters);


                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadOperationCount", counters.ReadOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteOperationCount", counters.WriteOperationCount);
```

the error is for that line calling GetProcesIoCounters()

Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'System.IntPtr*' g:\RobDevI5-Raid-0\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Code\CsExtensions.cs  416 42  g:...\WebSite2\

UPDAT - Code That seem to work though i could not verify it is using unsafe properly

signeture with unsafe

```
    [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    unsafe static extern bool GetProcessMemoryInfo(IntPtr* hProcess, out PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS Memcounters, int size);
```

code with my "unsafe"

```
        public static class IO
        {
            public static unsafe Dictionary<string, ulong> GetALLIO(Process procToRtrivIO)
            {
                IO_COUNTERS counters;
                Dictionary<string, ulong> retCountIoDict = new Dictionary<string, ulong>();
                IntPtr* Hw = (IntPtr*)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
                GetProcessIoCounters(Hw, out counters);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadOperationCount", counters.ReadOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteOperationCount", counters.WriteOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherOperationCount", counters.OtherOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadTransferCount", counters.ReadTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteTransferCount", counters.WriteTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherTransferCount", counters.OtherTransferCount);
                return retCountIoDict;
                //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
                //    " Mb of data.";

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you need to change a few things, shown below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
static class Nat
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential]
    struct IO_COUNTERS
    {
        public ulong ReadOperationCount;
        public ulong WriteOperationCount;
        public ulong OtherOperationCount;
        public ulong ReadTransferCount;
        public ulong WriteTransferCount;
        public ulong OtherTransferCount;
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    unsafe static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr ProcessHandle, out IO_COUNTERS IoCounters);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 40)]
    private struct PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS
    {
        public uint cb;
        public uint PageFaultCount;
        public uint PeakWorkingSetSize;
        public uint WorkingSetSize;
        public uint QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
        public uint PagefileUsage;
        public uint PeakPagefileUsage;
    }

    [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    unsafe static extern bool GetProcessMemoryInfo(IntPtr* hProcess, out PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS* Memcounters, int size);

    public static class IO
    {
        unsafe public static Dictionary<string, ulong> GetALLIO(Process procToRtrivIO)
        {
            IO_COUNTERS counters;
            Dictionary<string, ulong> retCountIoDict = new Dictionary<string, ulong>();
            IntPtr ptr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

            GetProcessIoCounters(ptr, out counters);
            retCountIoDict.Add("ReadOperationCount", counters.ReadOperationCount);
            retCountIoDict.Add("WriteOperationCount", counters.WriteOperationCount);
            retCountIoDict.Add("OtherOperationCount", counters.OtherOperationCount);
            retCountIoDict.Add("ReadTransferCount", counters.ReadTransferCount);
            retCountIoDict.Add("WriteTransferCount", counters.WriteTransferCount);
            retCountIoDict.Add("OtherTransferCount", counters.OtherTransferCount);
            return retCountIoDict;
            //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
            //    " Mb of data.";

        }
    }
    public static class Mem
    {
        unsafe public static Dictionary<string, uint> GetAllMem(Process procToRtrivMem)
        {

            PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS* MemCounters;
            Dictionary<string, uint> retCountMemDict = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
            IntPtr ptr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

            GetProcessMemoryInfo(&ptr, out MemCounters, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS))); //MemCounters.cb);
            retCountMemDict.Add("cb", MemCounters->cb);
            retCountMemDict.Add("PageFaultCount", MemCounters->PageFaultCount);
            retCountMemDict.Add("PeakWorkingSetSize", MemCounters->PeakWorkingSetSize);
            retCountMemDict.Add("WorkingSetSize", MemCounters->WorkingSetSize);
            retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters->QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage);
            retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters->QuotaPagedPoolUsage);

            retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters->QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage);
            retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters->QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage);
            retCountMemDict.Add("PagefileUsage", MemCounters->PagefileUsage);
            retCountMemDict.Add("PeakPagefileUsage", MemCounters->PeakPagefileUsage);

            return retCountMemDict;
            //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
            //    " Mb of data.";

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for trying and implement that (now you can add that to your extentions if it is interesting) i am now going to benchmark the differences between unsafe and stanadrt code to see if there's notesable difference and that's how i will learn when it is required to use it as ultimately i am trying to learn how to program c# with best performance even though i am still not that experienced !

Comment: say did you test it to work cause i did manage to make it work unsafe  i will post my code as well

Comment: could you show the code that in signeture and tell if you have tested it? , as it is now it does not (i just notiesd didnt changer `.` to `->`

Comment: still it does compile but gives an error on runtime, exactly where you populate the Dictionary first line :
`An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Code.jub7banp.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
`

Comment: I've edited the above to include the lot. It got past that point for me, although it failed when it tried to access the counters as the address returned was 0x00000000.

Comment: ,hey do you know why, any clues

Comment: did you know about `fixed`, or your code did not need to implement "fixed" in this case (searching "using fixed for unsafe c#" you could see this link also at  4th result)
https://www.google.co.il/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=using+fixed+for+unsafe+c%23&oq=using+fixed+for+unsafe+c%23&gs_l=hp.3...1624.19528.0.20063.41.33.6.2.2.0.232.3896.3j27j2.32.0...0.0...1c.1.17.hp.UdTfmCfuB74

Comment: class Class1
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern unsafe uint GetWindowsDirectory(byte* lpBuffer,uint uSize);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[512]; 
        unsafe 
        {
            fixed(byte *pbuff=buff)GetWindowsDirectory(pbuff,512);
        }
        ASCIIEncoding ae = new ASCIIEncoding();
        System.Console.WriteLine(ae.GetString(buff));
    }
}

Comment: Yep the import was wrong it should be unsafe static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr ProcessHandle, out IO_COUNTERS IoCounters);

Comment: wow thaks for that ! for your time, though one more question . in your last edit few hours ago you added to dictionary `I/O` vs `Mem` differently but seems that the rest of the code is the same so why once with mem it's: `dict.Add("name", counter->value)`  and with IO it's: `dict.Add("name", counter.value)` ?

Comment: That's ok. -> is for when you want to access a member of a pointer. I didn't check the import for the other method so if it doesn't work you may need to google it and adjust it.

Comment: thanks, it means that it should work for io just the same as you managed to get it to work with the mem ? as long as IO part signeture is fine i just copy all code as u did ?

Comment: I'd just try calling it. If the call doesn't return what you'd expect try taking the *s out of the signiture, and alter the code to be like the other one. It's probably worth checking the return values from each of these, as they'll both return false if there is a problem calling them.

Answer (score 3):

Necromancing.
The accepted answer contains code that doesn't work. 
Here's the corrected version that does work:

```
namespace MemoryInfo
{


    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Nat.Mem.GetAllMem(proc);
            Nat.IO.GetALLIO(proc);
        }
    }



    // http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/psapi.getprocessmemoryinfo
    static class Nat
    {


        // [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        // public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct IO_COUNTERS
        {
            public ulong ReadOperationCount;
            public ulong WriteOperationCount;
            public ulong OtherOperationCount;
            public ulong ReadTransferCount;
            public ulong WriteTransferCount;
            public ulong OtherTransferCount;
        }


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 40)]
        private struct PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS
        {
            public uint cb; // The size of the structure, in bytes (DWORD).
            public uint PageFaultCount; // The number of page faults (DWORD).
            public uint PeakWorkingSetSize; // The peak working set size, in bytes (SIZE_T).
            public uint WorkingSetSize; // The current working set size, in bytes (SIZE_T).
            public uint QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage; // The peak paged pool usage, in bytes (SIZE_T).
            public uint QuotaPagedPoolUsage; // The current paged pool usage, in bytes (SIZE_T).
            public uint QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage; // The peak nonpaged pool usage, in bytes (SIZE_T).
            public uint QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage; // The current nonpaged pool usage, in bytes (SIZE_T).
            public uint PagefileUsage; // The Commit Charge value in bytes for this process (SIZE_T). Commit Charge is the total amount of memory that the memory manager has committed for a running process.
            public uint PeakPagefileUsage; // The peak value in bytes of the Commit Charge during the lifetime of this process (SIZE_T).
        }


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private unsafe static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(System.IntPtr ProcessHandle, out IO_COUNTERS IoCounters);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private unsafe static extern bool GetProcessMemoryInfo(System.IntPtr hProcess, out PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS counters, uint size);


        public static class IO
        {
            unsafe public static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, ulong> GetALLIO(System.Diagnostics.Process procToRtrivIO)
            {
                IO_COUNTERS counters;
                System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, ulong> retCountIoDict = 
                    new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, ulong>();
                System.IntPtr ptr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

                GetProcessIoCounters(ptr, out counters);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadOperationCount", counters.ReadOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteOperationCount", counters.WriteOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherOperationCount", counters.OtherOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadTransferCount", counters.ReadTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteTransferCount", counters.WriteTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherTransferCount", counters.OtherTransferCount);
                return retCountIoDict;
                //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
                //    " Mb of data.";

            }
        } // End Class IO 


        public static class Mem
        {
            unsafe public static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, uint> GetAllMem(System.Diagnostics.Process procToRtrivMem)
            {
                PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS MemCounters;
                System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, uint> retCountMemDict = 
                    new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, uint>();
                System.IntPtr ptr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
                uint nativeStructSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS));


                GetProcessMemoryInfo(ptr, out MemCounters, nativeStructSize); //MemCounters.cb);
                retCountMemDict.Add("cb", MemCounters.cb);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PageFaultCount", MemCounters.PageFaultCount);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PeakWorkingSetSize", MemCounters.PeakWorkingSetSize);
                retCountMemDict.Add("WorkingSetSize", MemCounters.WorkingSetSize);
                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaPagedPoolUsage);

                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage", MemCounters.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PagefileUsage", MemCounters.PagefileUsage);
                retCountMemDict.Add("PeakPagefileUsage", MemCounters.PeakPagefileUsage);

                return retCountMemDict;
                //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
                //    " Mb of data.";
            }


        } // End Class Mem

    }




}
```

Comment: after 2+  years i  am amazed you've stumbled upon this question, i really don't  recall  using  it by now,   to determine how  did it perform  and what  were the results and  i  believe you  know what you are  talking about , i'll do my best to make  some time for this code  review  it  once again, thanks a  lot  Mr  Steiger !

Comment: @LoneXcoder: I found this page in search of an example for GetProcessMemoryInfo in C#. My problem was I used sizeof instead of Marshal.Sizeof. Rich on the other hand doesn't seem to understand pointers.

Comment: And no need for using 'unsafe' either in this code

Answer (score 1):

I think your web config line is missing the compilerOptions="/unsafe+" part

e.g.

```
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" compilerOptions="/unsafe+" warningLevel="4" />
    </compilers>
```

from

Comment: see the update please as it now even more complex for me to understand where exactly to put all those ****

Comment: Ok you need to use the & symbol to pass the pointer address. Something like &(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle)

Comment: i'm looking into that now i will try all options but if you could past into your vs, that is if you have some expreince with unmanaged/unsafe code i would ask for that so i will not waste another hour or so ..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to understand what the *asterisk* represents.  In C#, as in other C-like languages, it denotes a pointer type.  For example:

```
int *
```

...represents a "pointer to an int".  That is, the value of this variable indicates a memory location that contains an int.  C# and other .NET languages implement something called type-safety which means that it is difficult to misinterpret values in memory (for example, try to read a string at a memory location that actually contains an int) and this is broadly-speaking a useful thing.  However, sometimes, when you're interacting with native code, it is useful to be able to deal in terms of pointers.  This subverts the type-safety mechanism and therefore your code must be marked `unsafe` and you need to compile with the `/unsafe` switch as already noted.

You seem to suggest that you had an either/or decision between p/invoke and using unsafe code.  In my experience this seldom arises because the 2 techniques exist to solve different problems.  P/invoke allows you to interact with native code in a way that normally doesn't require you to use unsafe code, but in truth it depends on the nature of the native code you're interacting with.

When you ask whether your "safe mode" code "should it be also treated with the astrics?" I hope my explanation shows you that you don't *treat code with asterisks* but you declare variables as needed on a case-by-case basis.

In addition your p/invoke declaration for `GetProcessIoCounters` looks wrong.  You seldom see a parameter of type `IntPtr *`.  Check out http://pinvoke.net to look up the correct declaration.

To clear up some more terminology, code can be managed or unmanaged.  C# code is always managed.  Unmanaged code would be written in one of many languages, such as C, C++, etc.  C# code, while always managed, can be type-safe (the default) or you can mark blocks of C# code as unsafe, which allows you to use pointer types.

Comment: thanks for that explentaion ...if i got it right or not, lets just ask another time , unsafe is not needed here cause using `[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]   unsafe static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr*` .... which is Pinvoke code, is that already **is** unsafe or unmanaged or both  ? or just unmanged? ,  meaning (eventully), that using `unsafe` keyword with pointers to that type /variable in memory is not going to add some performance boost (even a little )

Comment: I think that's correct.  You don't need unsafe in the p/invoke declaration and nor do you need pointer types in the parameter list.  Using pointers does not in itself improve performance, although pointers might enable more efficient algorithms in some circumstances.  You would have to _really_ care about performance to explore this, and you should explore all .NET performance measures first.  See my edit for more clarification on terminology.

Comment: it apears you were right Mr martin , with not posting the code, and i should refrain use of `unsafe` unless it is absolutly crutial. and the honor of the correct answer goes to you mate. thanks for the information !